# Display data horizontally from MySQL table PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want make call two data in a cell; how to do that? My code is below:

I use this code [my source code](http://www.wavesdream.com/display-data-horizontally-from-mysql-table/)

but I want to insert in every cell email id, also that means two data in one cell.

How can I do that? Please give me a solution.

Comment: Welcome, please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U have to select both data from your table for example:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query ("SELECT email, id FROM members");
```

Now you can fetch your result

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
......
}
```

Now you can get your data by simply creating function to $i++, $row[$i].

```
echo $row[0]; //first email;
echo $row[1]; //first id
```

Put the both results inside one  to get your result.

Care that you should switch to mysqli or PDO as the mysql is no longer supported.

Comment: Show me your mysql table and i will create basic example